# I want to retrieve data from sharepoint list using c# and store them into SQL server DB tables. How can I do this?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sharepoint

```
string strUrl = "some url";
        using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(strUrl))
        {
            using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = oWeb.Lists["TargetList"];

                foreach (SPField field in list.Fields)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(field.Title);
                }
            }
        }
```

This code is entering break state showing "file not found exception" .Dont know where the problem is. 
Also I want to parse the sharepoint list.
After this how will I insert the data into tables created in my database

Comment: Are you running this code from a SharePoint web server (one of the servers running SharePoint) or from a different computer?

Answer (score -1):

```
        string strUrl = "some url";
        using (SPWeb myWeb = new SPSite(strUrl).OpenWeb())
        {
                SPListItemCollection items = myWeb.Lists["YourListName"].Items;

                string fieldValue1 = "";
                //...
                string fieldValuen = "";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection string");
                cmd.Connection = con;

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    con.Open();
                    foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                    {
                        fieldValue1 = item["column 1 name in SPList"].ToString();
                        //...
                        fieldValuen = item["column n name in SPList"].ToString();

                        string sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(field1ColumnName, ..., fieldnColumnName) VALUES('" + fieldValue1 + "', ...,'" + fieldValue1 + "')";

                        cmd.CommandText = sqlCommand;

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    con.Close();
                }

        }
```

Comment: The code above isn't working properly (mine) .
I'm still trying to access the sharepoint list

Comment: change `SPWeb myWeb = site.OpenWeb();` to  `SPWeb myWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;`

Comment: Please have a look on the question again
I have edited it

Comment: What type of your application?

Comment: It's a sharepoint list. And actually I don't have sharepoint.dll in my machine I have installed through runtime nuget.packages the sharpoint distribution for my project. There are no errors in my build but when i'm running this console application project its throwing "file not found exception" and entering break state

Comment: Can you please further explain. I'm totally new to this

Comment: What namspace do we need to use for "SPListItems" ?I'm currently using using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem , https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.items(v=office.15).aspx